# marionette create sub menu in one of menu tabs

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I work on site admin application and use marionette. And my problem is - how to organize views and applications for next requirements. Thanks for any help!

There are main menu on header - **Users management**, **Evenets**, **General settings**

And when user clicked to **Users management** On main region must shows additional menu with
**Users** **Groups** **Permissions** items and by default list of users (first tab is active).
Each item on click should shows coresponding view with list of entities.

And my question is how to organize applications, views and interaction between them?
Is sub menu part of users list view or it independent view? Which type of marionette view it must be?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like typical web page where it would be much easier to just render HTML on the backend and not build a web-application.

As for structure, there is no one correct way, but I found these couple example projects as decent start to evaluate the best structure:

- https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail
- https://github.com/Foxandxss/bbclonemail
- https://github.com/brian-mann/sc02-loading-views

They all use slightly different structure and coupling. You have to decide yourself which one is best suited for your case.

In your case I guess main application with main region where you show different sub-applications based on user selection (tabs). For specific interaction patterns look at the examples. Try to decouple everything, don't pass around references instead emit and listen to events.

I've built and work with couple bigger web applications and I recommend to no go that path unless there is a reason to do that. Admin interface sounds like something you can "quickly" setup using existing frameworks like `django-admin`, `flask-admin`, Rails scaffolding, `express-admin`, well you get the idea. Then again I don't know anything about the project.